# Resample the dataset based on 2 unique columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset where I have extracted 2 columns : date_1 and date_2. the dataframe has a size of 800 entries.

I have another dataframe1 having 20000 entries with date_1 and date_2 such that there are duplicated values and extra values. I want to remove the values which are not present in first dataframe (date_1, date_2 combination) from the second dataframe and store them somewhere else. Can anyone help me understand achieving the same.

**EDIT :** I have another column in dataframe 1 named value_1. It is the aggregated value. I want to distribute the column value to the entries created as well such that total for date_1, date_2 in second dataframe adds upto the dataframe1 value

example :

df1

```
date_1     date_2    value 
1/1/2019   2/2/2019  1000
```

Expected df2

```
date_1     date_2    value 
1/1/2019   2/2/2019  300
1/1/2019   2/2/2019  10
1/1/2019   2/2/2019  90
1/1/2019   2/2/2019  500
1/1/2019   2/2/2019  50
1/1/2019   2/2/2019  50
```

Thanks

Comment: If not working my solution, can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for both `DataFrame`s ?

Comment: Ok, can you add expected output?

Comment: @jezrael df2 is the expected output, we remove the values not present. as you can see the total value is coming to be 1000 for 6 entries.

Comment: So in another words need distribute `1000` from `df1['value']` to column `df2['value']` ? What is logic of distribution? Why `300, 10, ...` ?

Comment: @jezrael We can distribute it randomly, aggregately the value is already following the distribution, The major idea is to create a sample of 14k entries from df1 to create a dataset.

Comment: @jezrael Did you get the question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201189/discussion-between-user3759616-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `indicator` parameter and then filter by `eq` for `==` with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), for removed rows filter with `~` for invert mask:

```
df = df2.merge(df1, on=['date_1', 'date_2'], how='left', indicator=True)

mask = df['_merge'].eq('both')
df21 = df[mask]

df22 = df[~mask]
```

Comment: I have edited the question, Can you please edit your answer according to it